# morphia module ObjectIdBinder already defined error

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am new to morphia, mongoDB and playframework. I am trying to use these for production. My code was working just fine the last time i run it last week. This morning, i keep getting the following error and i have no idea how to fix it:

> 10:20:53,048 INFO  ~ Starting /home/user/NetBeansProjects/um
>   10:20:53,056 WARN  ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is
>   deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.morphia) 10:20:53,060
>   INFO  ~ Module morphia is available
>   (/home/user/play-1.2.2/modules/morphia-1.2.1beta6) 10:20:53,062
>   INFO  ~ Module morphia is available
>   (/home/user/play-1.2.2/modules/morphia-1.2.1beta6) 10:20:54,538
>   WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode 10:20:54,828 INFO  ~
>   Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
>   10:21:03,741 ERROR ~
>
> @67c6i5h2e Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /
>
> Compilation error (In
>   {module:morphia-1.2.1beta6}/app/morphia/ObjectIdBinder.java around
>   line 12) The file
>   {module:morphia-1.2.1beta6}/app/morphia/ObjectIdBinder.java could not
>   be compiled. Error raised is : The type ObjectIdBinder is already
>   defined
>
> play.exceptions.CompilationException: The type ObjectIdBinder is
>   already defined   at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:672)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:516)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:278)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:412)
>     at play.Play.start(Play.java:482)   at
>   play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:596)    at
>   play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:186)    at Invocation.HTTP
>   Request(Play!)

i dont remember changing anything in the code too.

Answer (score 3):

This shows that you are including module morphia twice. Once in application.conf. And the second time I asume in the dependencies file.

```
10:20:53,056 WARN ~ Declaring modules in application.conf is deprecated. Use dependencies.yml instead (module.morphia) 
10:20:53,060 INFO ~ Module morphia is available (/home/user/play-1.2.2/modules/morphia-1.2.1beta6) 
10:20:53,062 INFO ~ Module morphia is available (/home/user/play-1.2.2/modules/morphia-1.2.1beta6)
```

Check Your dependencies.yml file in your project conf folder, there should be the 
"- morphia" or "- play -> morphia" item.
As the first is now deprecated, you should probably suppress the following :

```
module.morphia=../morphia
```

Comment: Thank you. MOrphia module was being loaded twice so i suppressed one as u sed. Got rid of the dependencies  version of it and moved the jar files to the projects local module directory.